# How to retrieve data from Firebase and show them in a autocomplete text view in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, autocompletetextview

Item should be retrieve according to the user's search. For example, country name search->show suggestion countries list in autocomplete text view-> user can select one country. (country names list should be in Firebase)

please help if anyone knows

Answer (score 0):

you can check out this question I did ask, it contains answer that you want, even though it uses cloud-firestore

[list of documents when using autocompletetextview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53352833/5972985)

```
private var autoComplete: ArrayAdapter<String>? = null

mFirebaseFirestore.collection("tblProductItems").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, exception ->
    if (exception != null) {
        showShortToast(this@NewOrderActivity, exception.toString())
    }

    for (suggestSnapshot in querySnapshot!!.documents) {
        val suggestion = suggestSnapshot.getString("name")

        //Add the retrieved string to the list
        autoComplete?.add(suggestion)
    }
}


    textCurrentSearch.setAdapter(autoComplete)
```