# Get a firestore document id from autocompletetextview onItemClickListener items

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, autocompletetextview

My problem is very simple and clear. I already did fetch data from the firestore cloud-firestore database, it is being suggested in AutoCompleteTextView very well, and clickable. However, I want to get the firebase cloud-firestore document id of the selected item. Tested with toasting it

```
private var autoComplete: ArrayAdapter<String>? = null
private var itemId: String? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    readData(object: MyCallback {
        override fun onCallback(value: ArrayAdapter<String>) {
            Log.d(TAG, "The list has: " + value.count.toString() + " items.")
        }
    })

    textCurrentSearch.setAdapter(autoComplete)

    textCurrentSearch.onItemClickListener = OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->

        showShortToast(this@NewOrderActivity, "Item on cloud-firestore id: " + itemId!! + "Item on ArrayAdapter id: " + id)
    }
}

fun showShortToast(context: Context, message: String) {
    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

private fun readData(myCallback : MyCallback) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Before attaching the listener!")

    mFirebaseFirestore.collection("tblProductItems").get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Inside onComplete function!")
            for (document in task.result!!) {
                val name = document.data["name"].toString()

                itemId = document.id

                autoComplete?.add(name)
            }

            myCallback.onCallback(autoComplete!!)

        } else showShortToast(this@NewOrderActivity, task.exception!!.toString())
    }.addOnSuccessListener {
        showShortToast(this@NewOrderActivity, "")
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "After attaching the listener!")
}

interface MyCallback {
    fun onCallback(value: ArrayAdapter<String>)
}
```

I tried with the

```
itemId = suggestSnapshot.id
```

but it does not get me the id of the selected product item doument. Kindly help with anything constructive, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, please move the lines where you are setting the addapter and you are attaching the lister right inside the callback like so:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    mFirebaseFirestore.collection("tblProductItems").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, exception ->
        if (exception != null) {
            showShortToast(this@NewOrderActivity, exception.toString())
        }

        for (suggestSnapshot in querySnapshot!!.documents) {
            val suggestion = suggestSnapshot.getString("name")

            itemId = suggestSnapshot.id

            //Add the retrieved string to the list
            autoComplete?.add(suggestion)
        }
        textCurrentSearch.setAdapter(autoComplete)
        textCurrentSearch.onItemClickListener = OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            showShortToast(this@NewOrderActivity, "Item on cloud-firestore id: " + itemId!! + "Item on ArrayAdapter id: " + id)
        }
    }
}
```

Firebase API is asynchronous meaning that the data is available only if you wait for it. For more informations, I recommend you also see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594772/how-to-return-a-list-from-firestore-database-as-a-result-of-a-function-in-kotlin/51595202)**.

Comment: it still does not work, my code is working, it suggests the products to the AutoCompleteTextView, but I want whenever I select or click the suggested items, I want to Toast its auto-generated id from firebase. check my toast line

    showShortToast(this@NewOrderActivity, "Item on cloud-firestore id: " + itemId!! + "Item on ArrayAdapter id: " + id)

Comment: I have changed the code to look like the post you shared but i'm still stuck somewhere... I have used the MyCallback interface, I log the ArrayAdapter.count.toString() very well, how do I pass the firestore id to the clicked or selected item? Please help...

Comment: Have you tried to use `suggestSnapshot.key` instead of `suggestSnapshot.id`?

Comment: Is there everything alright, have you solved the issue?

Comment: hey man, nope it still has an issue...key cannot be casted into String it suggests in the AutoCompleteTextView, but I cannot toast the auto id of the selected item. I tried to use your strategy of the CallBacks

Comment: And does it work with the callback? Have you tried to use `suggestSnapshot.key` instead of `suggestSnapshot.id`?

Comment: Cannot access key, it is invisible, (private in a supertype),in QueryDocumentSnapshot

Comment: The simplest way I can think of is to add at every iteration the id to a list and then inside the OnItemClickListener to get the corespoding id like `listOfIds.get(position);` Give it a try, ok?

Comment: yeap, lemme try, BRB

Comment: Would you check this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53426737/5972985)

Comment: Try that solution and tell me if it works. Ok, I'll check your question and if I'll know the answer, I'll write it to you.

Comment: hey it does not work, as soon as you start typing the position of one of the list changes, so they can't be the same.

Comment: So I basically said to do the exact thing that you do right now. Create another list named `listOfIds` and in the same way you are adding `autoComplete?.add(suggestion)` add ids to the list like this: `listOfIds.add(itemId)`. So after the iteration is finished, you'll have a list full of ids. So using inside the OnItemClickListener `listOfIds.get(position);` will get the id of the corresponding clicked position, right?