# How to get a list of Strings from inside of a document Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have stored a list of Strings inside a document.i have given it a name("name") now i am trying to get it on the client side but do not know how to do it exactly. i can see that if my field is of type number i can use `getLong("Fieldname")` but i am unable to figure it out how to get back a list of type Strings.
My code so far

```
FirebaseFirestore getlistofbrands=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
getlistofbrands.collection(FireStoreConstants.COL_BRANDNAMESONLY).document("Brands").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
        List<String> listofbrandsfromfirestore=queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().toArray(String.class);
```

also tried this

```
List<String> listofbrandsfromfirestore=queryDocumentSnapshots.toObjects(String.class);
```

how i uploaded the data

```
   Map < String, Object > docData = new HashMap < > ();
   List < String > deviceNameList = new ArrayList < String > ();
   deviceNameList.add("brand1");
   deviceNameList.add("brand2");
   deviceNameList.add("brand3");
   deviceNameList.add("brand4");
   docData.put("name", deviceNameList);
  firebaseFirestore.collection("FireStoreConstants.COL_BRANDNAMESONLY")
  .document("Brands").set(docData).addOnSuccessListener(new 
  OnSuccessListener < Void > () {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
  Log.d(TAG, "Repository:onSuccess:");
  }
  }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
  @Override
  public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
  Log.d(TAG, "Repository:error" + e.toString());
  }
   });
```

Comment: Always copy your code directly into the question.

Comment: Please replace the picture of code with the actual code you used as text.

Comment: Please add you database structure and indicate what is the expected result. And please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for your comment i have a collection "COL-BRANDNAMESONLY" inside that collection i have a document "
Brands

" inside that document i have a list of brands i simply want to know how to retrieve this list from Firestore you can have a visual of my DB at firestore in this image link http://prntscr.com/ljtnsv

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i have replaced the image with code can you help me now? I will be very thankful.

Comment: Since you store the brand names in a single document, I doubt `QuerySnapshot` is the right class to get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you store the brand names in a single document, I doubt QuerySnapshot is the right class to get back. As far as I can see, you'll want to use [`getData()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getData()) to get the `Map<String, Object>` that Firestore uses for your `List`:

```
getlistofbrands
  .collection(FireStoreConstants.COL_BRANDNAMESONLY)
  .document("Brands")
  .get()
  .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());

                Map<String, String> brandsMap = (Map<String, String>)documen.getData().getData("AllBrands");
                List<String> brands = new LinkedList<String>();

                for (String key: brandsMap.keySet()) {
                    brands.add(brandsMap.get(key));
                }

                // TODO: use the brands list
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
  });
```

You might also want to try:

```
List<String> brands = brandsMap.value();
```

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Puffelen using your code and help from others i am now able to get my list back just used a function from some one else. i will put it in the answer section as in comments section it is not looking great Again thank you very much i was waiting for your answer since morning....

Comment: i up-voted the answer but it says i need 15 reputation to reflect it publicly

Answer (score 0):

i used the code provided by @Frank van and used this function to cast my Object to a list of Strings

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends List<?>> T cast(Object obj) {
    return (T) obj;
}

 Object brandsobj = queryDocumentSnapshots.getData().get("AllBrands");
 List<String> allbrands = cast(brandsobj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this question post I had posted earlier. You can change from the ArrayAdapter that I have used to a List

[AutoCompleteTextView data from Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53352833/5972985)

Hope it helps you.