# Cloud Firestore don't display data on Fragments After Swipe

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have created an app with Firebase Cloud Firestore. I'm trying to list my orders to a recyclerview in between fragments. I have a Fragment: OrderListFragment

```
// RecyclerView
mOrderAdapter = object : OrderAdapter(getQuery(mFirebaseFirestore), this@OrderListFragment) {
        override fun onDataChanged() {
            super.onDataChanged()

            mRecyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        }

        override fun onError(e: FirebaseFirestoreException) {
            super.onError(e)

            showShortToast(context!!, "Error: " + e.toString())

            // Show a snackbar on errors
            Snackbar.make(mSnackbarLayout!!, "Error: check logs for info.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
mRecyclerView.adapter = mOrderAdapter
```

and two Fragments extending the above Fragment:

1.

```
class RecentOrderFragment : OrderListFragment() {

    override fun getQuery(firebaseFirestore: FirebaseFirestore): Query {

        return firebaseFirestore.collection("tblOrders")
            .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .whereEqualTo("isDraft", false)
            .whereEqualTo("isPaidFor", true)
            .limit(LIMIT.toLong())
    }
}
```

2.

```
class MyOrdersFragment : OrderListFragment() {

    override fun getQuery(firebaseFirestore: FirebaseFirestore): Query {
        return firebaseFirestore.collection("tblOrders")
            .whereEqualTo("userId", uid)
            .whereEqualTo("isDraft", false)
            .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .limit(LIMIT.toLong())
    }
}
```

At first, it displays the orders, but when I swipe from one fragment, and go back, the previous fragment can't display the recyclerview again. Actually now it does not display at all

Comment: If you said that you can swipe between page, thenI assume that you use ViewPager. Did your ViewPager adapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter()? If yes, please try to use FragmentPagerAdapter() instead of  FragmentStatePagerAdapter(). Hope that my comment help you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment, but it uses FragmentPagerAdapter()